# Pause stripe subscription for x months and the remaining amount not used should be systematically refunded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Api in implementing Online Subscription on my system. I have 2 monthly plans and also I am implementing recurring charge every first day of the month.

I wanted to know if it is possible to pause subscription for X months? If yes, If my user paused his subscription for 1 or 2 months and he paused it in the middle of the month, is it possible to issue a refund from stripe for the remaining days that are already paid?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "pause" a subscription in two different ways:

- if you already know when the pause should end, you can [update the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription) with [`trial_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription-trial_end) set to the timestamp of the next desired billing date, and [`prorate`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription-prorate) set to `false`.
- if you don't know how long the pause will last, you should [cancel the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription), and [create a new subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) when you want to resume billing your customer.

If you want to refund for unused time, you'll have to compute the amount of the refund then [create a (partial) refund](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund) using the subscription's latest charge.